# Error using "TermDocumentMatrix" and "Dist" functions in R

Tags: r, text-mining, text-classification, text-analysis

I have been trying to replicate the example [here](http://www.rexamine.com/2014/06/text-mining-in-r-automatic-categorization-of-wikipedia-articles/): but I have had some problems along the way.

Everything worked fine until here:

```
docsTDM <- TermDocumentMatrix(docs8)
```

> Error in UseMethod("meta", x) : 
>             no applicable method for 'meta' applied to an object of class "character"
>             In addition: Warning message:
>             In mclapply(unname(content(x)), termFreq, control) :
>               all scheduled cores encountered errors in user code

So I was able to fix that error modifying this previous step by changing this:

```
docs8 <- tm_map(docs7, tolower)
```

To this:

```
docs8 <- tm_map(docs7, content_transformer(tolower))
```

But then I got in trouble again with:

```
docsdissim <- dissimilarity(docsTDM, method = "cosine")
```

> Error: could not find function "dissimilarity"

Then I learned that the "dissimilarity" function was replaced by the `dist` function, so I did:

```
docsdissim <- dist(docsTDM, method = "cosine")
```

> Error in crossprod(x, y)/sqrt(crossprod(x) * crossprod(y)) : 
>             non-conformable arrays

And there is where I'm stuck.

By the way, my R version is :

> R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) running on CentOS 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
docsdissim <- proxy::dist(docsTDM, method = "cosine")
```

to

```
docsdissim <- dist(as.matrix(docsTDM), method = "cosine")
```

`dist` requires as input a numeric matrix, data frame or "dist" object and event though a termdocumentmatrix is a matrix, it needs to be transformed here.