# How to replace tokens (words) with stemmed versions of words from my own table?

Tags: r, nlp, text-mining, stemming, quanteda

I got data like this (simplified):

```
library(quanteda)
```

sample data

```
myText <- c("ala ma kotka", "kasia ma pieska")  
myDF <- data.frame(myText)
myDF$myText <- as.character(myDF$myText)
```

tokenization

```
tokens <- tokens(myDF$myText, what = "word",  
             remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_punct = TRUE,
             remove_symbols = TRUE, remove_hyphens = TRUE)
```

stemming with my own data
sample dictionary

```
Origin <- c("kot", "pies")
Word <- c("kotek","piesek")

myDict <- data.frame(Origin, Word)

myDict$Origin <- as.character(myDict$Origin)
myDict$Word <- as.character(myDict$Word)
```

what i got

```
tokens[1]
[1] "Ala"   "ma"    "kotka"
```

what i would like to get

```
tokens[1]
[1] "Ala"   "ma"    "kot"
tokens[2]
[1] "Kasia"   "ma"    "pies"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A similar question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46122591/a-lemmatizing-function-using-a-hash-dictionary-does-not-work-with-tm-package-in/46124729#46124729), but since that question's title (and accepted answer) do not make the obvious link, I will show you how this applies to your question specifically.  I'll also provide additional detail below to implement your own basic stemmer using wildcards for the suffixes.

#### Manually mapping stems to inflected forms

The simplest way to do this is by using a custom dictionary where the keys are your stems, and the values are the inflected forms.  You can then use `tokens_lookup()` with the `exclusive = FALSE, capkeys = FALSE` options to convert the inflected terms into their stems.

Note that I have modified your example a little to simplify it, and to correct what I think were mistakes.

```
library("quanteda")
packageVersion("quanteda")
[1] ‘0.99.9’

# no need for the data.frame() call
myText <- c("ala ma kotka", "kasia ma pieska")  
toks <- tokens(myText, 
               remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_punct = TRUE,
               remove_symbols = TRUE, remove_hyphens = TRUE)

Origin <- c("kot", "kot", "pies", "pies")
Word <- c("kotek", "kotka", "piesek", "pieska")
```

Then we create the dictionary, as follows.  As of quanteda v0.99.9, values with the same keys are merged, so you could have a list mapping multiple, different inflected forms to the same keys.  Here, I had to add new values since the inflected forms in your original `Word` vector were not found in the `myText` example.

```
temp_list <- as.list(Word) 
names(temp_list) <- Origin
(stem_dict <- dictionary(temp_list))
## Dictionary object with 2 key entries.
## - [kot]:
##   - kotek, kotka
## - [pies]:
##   - piesek, pieska
```

Then `tokens_lookup()` does its magic.

```
tokens_lookup(toks, dictionary = stem_dict, exclusive = FALSE, capkeys = FALSE)
## tokens from 2 documents.
## text1 :
## [1] "ala" "ma"  "kot"
## 
## text2 :
## [1] "kasia" "ma"    "pies"
```

#### Wildcarding all stems from common roots

An alternative is to implement your own stemmer using the "glob" wildcarding to represent all suffixes for your `Origin` vector, which (here, at least) produces the same results:

```
temp_list <- lapply(unique(Origin), paste0, "*")
names(temp_list) <- unique(Origin)
(stem_dict2 <- dictionary(temp_list))
# Dictionary object with 2 key entries.
# - [kot]:
#   - kot*
# - [pies]:
#   - pies*

tokens_lookup(toks, dictionary = stem_dict, exclusive = FALSE, capkeys = FALSE)
## tokens from 2 documents.
## text1 :
## [1] "ala" "ma"  "kot"
## 
## text2 :
## [1] "kasia" "ma"    "pies"
```

Comment: I would like to say a very big "thank you" for your complete answer and time taken to explain it perfectly.